# Store text in PHP array or MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, query-optimization

Lets say I've got 50 pages, and I want to write a description for about 30 of them.

The description will be about two paragraphs on each page.

*Is it more efficient for my server* if I save the descriptions in a MySQL database and then query on each page to see if there is a corresponding description, or is it best if I store them in an array in my PHP file and see if the element exists?

Extra Info:
I would edit the array file manually or the db entry through phpMyAdmin which would both take the same amount of time. Also it would only be me editing them so I don't have to worry about making a quick edit file.

Comment: How will you persist the array between requests?

Comment: I think it is probably the same performance-wise, but you will be very happy if you have to upgrade the system later, if you do it in a MySQL database.

Comment: @Dogbert I think the array will be defined on script running.

Comment: @bearbin And the data will be stored where?

Comment: just set in the php file

Comment: or not if i use the database lol

Comment: Mysql, simply because its more versatile, and you have more development options down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

Store them in an array, in a sepparate file `data.php`, in this form:

```
<?php
return array(
  // here be data
);
```

In the caller script you use it like this:

```
$data = require 'data.php';
```

and then use the $data variable throughout the site, as needed. You could also split the array and use several files based on specific criterias, like "the language", or "article category" or whatever.

If you do it this way, you can always plug in an editor with a web interface to edit that array and store it back with `file_put_contents('data.php', '<?php return '. var_export($data));`, where `$data` has got its value after processing a `POST` form, for instance, which was generated from the old value of `$data`.

Really elegant, fast, and maintainable!

As a bonus, write helper functions around those serializations, deserializations, etc, such that if you ever change your mind (because your site grows and you end up with hundreds of such arrays), you only have to reimplement those functions to use a database backend, **without ever touching the rest of the codebase**.

Code reusability and maintanability at its peak! And you get it up and **running immediately**, without losing **the prospect of making it better** in the future, if required.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change those descriptions frequently, you can store them in array. But it'll be better to keep them in separated files, instead of keeping them all in one PHP file.

But your server can easily handle that kind of small rows. So do what is easy for you.

Maybe you can store them in database for adding/editing stuff and do a cache of it to read from your page.

Answer (score -1):

I would store the information in a DB. It is more slowy but more elegant.
If you want to do it with an array:

```
Class Page
{
    // global configuration
    private static $config = null;

    // individuel configuration
    public $title, $content;

    // constructor
    function __construct($page) {
        // get the configuration
        $config = self::getConfig();

        // cheack weather the page exists
        if(!isset($config[$page]))
            die('unknown page "'.$page.'"');

        // set some stuff
        $this->title = $config[$page]['title'];
        $this->content = $config[$page]['content'];
    }

    // get the configuration
    private function getConfig() {
        if(self::$config === null)
            self::$config = include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');
        return self::$config;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
return Array(
    'home' => Array(
        'title' => 'Welcome!',
        'content' => 'Welcome to my site!' /* maybe include some html for complxe stuff */
    )
);
```

Example:

```
$myPage = new Page('home');
echo $myPage->content;
```